# Linear algebra manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I need to write out the following product:

$$
(\beta - \beta_0)^T \Sigma (\beta - \beta_0)
$$

$\beta$ is a vector quantity and $\Sigma$ is a matrix. So the product returns a scalar. I am trying to multiply this out. Can I write:

$$
= \beta^T \Sigma \beta - \beta_0^T\Sigma \beta - \beta^T\Sigma\beta_0 + \beta_0^T\Sigma \beta_0
$$

Is this correct? Also if I know that my matrix $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. Can I perform some more simplifications?

Comment: You might also note that $\beta_0^T\Sigma\beta$ is a scalar so it equals its own transpose: $[\beta_0^T\Sigma\beta]^T=\beta^T\Sigma^T\beta_0$. In particular, if $\Sigma$ is symmetric, the middle two terms you have are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a legal move: matrix multiplication distributes over addition and the transpose is linear.

Additionally, if $\Sigma$ is diagonal, this simplifies things greatly. It will be a "weighted inner product" of $\beta-\beta_0$, where the weight on each coordinate is the corresponding entry in $\Sigma$.